# How to Locate the source List in data validation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an excel file, there is a column with a data validation field. And it has too many dropdowns. When I looked at the data validation, it has a `list` criteria and a source `=offices`. My problem is I want to copy all this values and I don't want to encode them one by one. Where can I locate this `offices` list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"offices" refers to a named formula or named range. You can use several approaches to find out what the name refers to.

Using Go To:

- hit the F5 key
- click the name in the list of names and hit OK

If the name does not show in the Go To dialog, it is defined with a dynamic formula. In this case you need the following approach with Name Manager:

- Open the Name Manager on the Formulas ribbon
- select the name "offices"
- click into the Refers to box.

That will highlight the range that the name refers to, even if there is a formula in the "Refers to" box.

Comment: this is what I got in the "refers to" box `=References!$G$2:$G$227` but I do not see highlighted cells.

Comment: Oh I found it. Thanks. the `references` sheet was just hidden. Thank you.